# Sync packages among Ubuntu(s)

Tags: sync, sharing

I have a number of Ubuntu computers. I'd like to sync among my computers all .deb packages installed via `apt-get install`. There were a way before using an Ubuntu One account and Ubuntu Software Center. nevertheless, this service is no longer available.

My question is if there is a similar way to share .deb packages among my computers in a similar way than before with Ubuntu One.